# How can I view all characters in Segoe UI Symbol, in Babelmap or character map? (particularly 1F381) Characters past FFFF

Tags: windows, unicode, babelmap, character-map

I notice that Character Map goes up to FFFF nothing beyond.

It doesn't go as far as 1F381

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f381/index.htm

Unicode Character 'WRAPPED PRESENT' (U+1F381)

But if I look up 1F381 in babelmap, it shows that Segoe UI Symbol has it

[image]

But I can't get babelmap to change the font to display all symbols in a particular font.

See in its main window babelmap isn't showing U+1F381

[image]

And character map I can choose Segoe UI Symbol but it doesn't display that codepoint. The last one it shows is U+FFFD but it stops there, which would of course is before U+1F381

Comment: as an aside ,prior to FFFF, if character map skips chars it's where it's not supported e.g. in segoe it goes straight from character U+16F0 to U+2000 got those or many of those are in the font codepoint 2000/2002. Still.. character map doesn't have beyond FFFF even when the font does. So looks like char map is only supporting up to 16 bits of unicode, which is maybe funny 'cos even utf-8 encoding should support encoding all/any chars, even 32 bits and is commonly used,

Comment: It doesn't show utf-8 either btw. only unicode codepoints which I guess is mostly utf-16 http://www.utf8-chartable.de/ (scroll down to see differences)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to work fine now. I'm not sure what I was doing wrong before.

You can choose "composite font" and it shows the character

or you can choose "single font" and it shows.

[image]

And there's babelpad too, which has that and even has tools..character map and its character map goes beyond FFFF even to 10FFFD

babelmap goes that far too

here's babelpad's character map goes even to 10FFFD

[image]